# Pandas get all columns without one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, if I have a dataframe called `df`, I can get one column with

```
df.column_one
```

and, I can get some specific columns with

```
df[['column_one', 'column_two']]
```

how I can get all columns without one specific?

Example: if I have a dataframe with n columns `col_1`, `col_2`, ... `col_n`,
How I can get all columns without `col_n`?

Comment: There is a little known method that does this: `df[df.columns.difference('col_n')]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this:

```
df.drop(['col_n'], axis=1)
```

or

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'col_n']
```

or

```
df.loc[:, df.columns - ['col_n']]
```

or as @IanS posted in the comment:

```
df[df.columns.difference('col_n')]
```

or using `filter()` function in junction with negative look ahead RegEx:

```
df.filter(regex=r'^((?!col_n).*)$')
```

Comment: There is also a little known method that does this: `df[df.columns.difference('col_n')]`.

Comment: @IanS, thanks! I've added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use df.drop:

```
df.drop('column_one',axis=1)
```